# UIImagePicker reappears after being image is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a `UIImagePicker` that keeps reappearing after I have selected an image.  My code is checking for a camera and then displaying the `UIImagePicker` based on the fact that there is no camera in the simulator.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }
    else {
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }
    self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self clear];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Do I need to force reload my initial view? Is there a smarter way to do this?

**EDIT**

I added a Bar Button to the Navigation Bar and im firing my code on that action. That fixed the issue and seems like a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `viewWillAppear` is being called everytime the `UIImagePickerController` disappears - because the view controller where you put the code is becoming visible again.

You can try creating the `UIImagePickerController` in `viewDidLoad` instead, or use a boolean property to check if it is calling it for the first time.

Comment: Beat my answer by at least 30 seconds! :)

Comment: Good that we agree on the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is invoked by the viewWillAppear method of your view controller.

When that fires, it displays a view controller modally. When you dismiss it, your view controller is uncovered. It's viewWillAppear method is invoked, which displays a new image picker, and the cycle continues...